# Flutter: Cloud Firestore does not call listeners immediately

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hive

In a Flutter app, I thought I'd try to replace Hive with Cloud Firestore, using realtime updates based on this Firebase guidance => [Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart_3)

I am finding Firebase listeners a little too laggy to use for user interactions that require responsiveness. Laggy meaning a half-second or so delay - enough that the user notices the delay in updating the UI, making the user experience poor.  For example, a user changes a record, and the UI then updates via a Firebase listener.

I have tried updating the UI using both a Firebase snapshot listener (the below code), and also using StreamBuilders.  Both methods exhibit the same lag.

The delay is not from the "round trip" of writing Cloud Firestore and then reading back. I am updating the UI directly from **local changes** that have not been written to the backend yet.  [Events for local changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) states that "*Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners immediately"*.  Using the code below, in the debug console, it verifies the data received in the Snapshot listener is indeed "Local" and not "Server".  So not the issue.

```
    Firestore.instance.collection('collection')
        .doc('uuid')
        .set('data');


    Firestore.instance.collection('collection')
        .doc('uuid')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
            final source = (event.metadata.hasPendingWrites) ? "Local" : "Server";
            debugPrint('$source data: ${event.data()}');
            // update the UI 
    });
```

**A last very important point**.  If I write to Firebase, and *immediately* call setState(), the UI updates immediately *with the new data*.  To me that indicates the lag is due to Firebase not calling listeners immediately.

Is there a property/setting/configuration required for Firebase to call listeners immediately?

I am  curious if there is anyone else who has worked with both Hive ValueListenableBuilders and Cloud Firestore StreamBuilder/Snapshot Listeners, and seen the same delay in calling listerners.

In the meantime, I have reverted to using Hive as an "intermediary" database between firebase database.  The Hive database only serves the purpose of writing Hive and quickly updating the UI via a ValueListenableBuilder.

Comment: Your title asks for a recommendation, which means it'll likely get closed. I recommend changing the question to solely focus on what doesn't work in Firestore the way that you expect it to. In addition, instead of saying "laggy", I recommend logging exact timestamps of when you start an operation, and when you get a result.

Comment: Thanks for that update. Note that none of your code write to the database, so it's all in all hard to see where the delay comes from. I really recommend editing your question to contain a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the timestamps I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Hi Frank.  Good feedback/input, thank you.  In this instance, it's a tricky thing to create reproducible code as there is much to setting up a Firebase database on which to test.  I was hoping there were others who tried to replace Hive with Cloud Firestore, saw the same issue, and found a way to address.

Comment: That's always possible of course, but chances of somebody being able to help drastically go up with a minimal repro.